# How to fix this material table with expandable row example when using mat-* elements

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mat-table

I'm trying to apply the same principles to get an expandable row for my tables in the "Table with expandable rows" [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples).

I have styled my version of the tables similarly but cannot get the expanded portion of the tables correctly rendered. The expanded details doesn't expand the corresponding row, it just renders on top of the table overlapping. The only difference with my version is that I'm using the custom `mat-*` elements to create the tables.

using native elements

```html
<table mat-table ...>
  ...
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

using mat-* elements

```html
<mat-table ...>
  ...
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </mat-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

[image]

From my understanding, it's the styling of the `mat-*` elements that's causing issues. I definitely had to make some tweaks to the style to fix some issues, but I don't know what else to do to fix the example completely.

```css
mat-table {
  width: 100%;
}

mat-row.example-detail-row {
  height: 0;
  min-height: initial; /* override mat-row styling */
}

mat-row.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):hover {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

mat-row.example-element-row:not(.example-expanded-row):active {
  background: #efefef;
}

.example-element-row, /* override mat-row styling */
.example-element-row mat-cell {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxylk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is that since the `<mat-row>` elements uses flex, I needed to use `flex-basis` to set the initial height of the detail row, rather than using `height`. That way the height could be adjusted when its content changes.

```css
mat-row.example-detail-row {
  /* height: 0; */ /* no */
  flex-basis: 0; /* yes */
  min-height: initial; /* override mat-row styling */
}
```

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxylk2-ycuxaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.scss)

Answer (score 1):

You rule for `mat-row.example-detail-row` will be applied to all `mat-row` elements. This is causing your `expandedDetail` rows to always have a `height: 0`

I changed the `example-detail-row` class to `hidden-detail` and added the following to the mat-row in the template:

```
[class.hidden-detail]="expandedElement !== row"
```

It seems to be working as expected now.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxylk2-qvdfuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot this part. I believe the underlying cause for this is that by default `tr` elements display as `table-row` and `mat-row` elements display as `flex`.

Comment: Thanks. I had actually figured out the issue. But ultimately in the end, I switched from using angular material for sticking with bootstrap.

Comment: I see, good call on flex-basis, that's a better solution.